# Tuple in list has less items than the function needs Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, tuples

I'm kinda new to Programming and Python and I'm self learning before going to uni so please be gentle, I'm a newbie. I hope my english won't have too many grammatical errors.

Basically I had this exercise in a book I'm currently reading to take a list of tuples as a function parameter, then take every item in the each tuple and put it to 2nd power and sum the items up.

My code looks like this and works good if my function call includes the same amount of arguments as the function for loop requires:

```
def summary(xs):
    for x,y,z in xs:
        print( x*x + y*y + z*z)


xs =[(2,3,4), (2,-3,4), (1,2,3)]

summary(xs)
```

However, If I use a list with less tuples than the function definition, I get an error: ValueError : not enough values to unpack(expected 3, got 0):

```
xs =[(2,3,4), (), (1,2,3)]
```

I would like to know how to make a function that would accept a tuple I shown before () - with no tuples, and the function would return 0. I have been trying multiple ways how to solve this for 2 days already and googling as well, but it occurs to me I'm either missing something or I'm not aware of a function i could use. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Use `none` instead of `()` and check for it in your function?

Comment: There are various ways to solve your problem. One way to solve it would be to iterate over the tuple with a special case for `len  == 0`. If you want to solve in a more pythonic way, you could have a look at list comprehensions. If you need further help, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to iterate over the tuple values, this would also be the way to tackle this problem in nearly every programming language:

```
def summary(xs):
    for item in xs:
        s = 0
        for value in item:
            s += value**2
        print(s)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
def summary(xs):
   for item in xs:
       result = sum([x**2 for x in item])
       print(result)
```

also note that `sum([])` will return `0` for an empty iterable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have no idea how I didn't think of looping the tuples by making a nested for loop, pretty simple and works flawlessly. I guess my biggest issue was how i viewed the tuples before, I was very confused what they even are, now I see they are something like nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `try` / `except`. In the below example, we use a generator and catch occasions when unpacking fails with `ValueError` and yield 0.

While you are learning, I highly recommend you practice writing functions which `return` or `yield` rather than using them to `print` values.

```
def summary(xs):
    for item in xs:
        try:
            yield sum(i**2 for i in item)
        except ValueError:
            yield 0

xs = [(2,3,4), (), (1,2,3)]

res = list(summary(xs))

print(res)

[29, 0, 14]
```

Or to actually utilise the generator in a lazy fashion:

```
for i in summary(xs):
    print(i)

29
0
14
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too, if I use 3 tuples or no tuples, If i use lets say 2 tuples in a list , it returns 0 even tho it should return some number, is there any way to fix this or should I use the solution from the user pask ?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just wondering what the yield thing does. Is it similar to print? I will look around later, if it's too long for a comment. Just wanna point out this book exercise requires way more knowledge and syntax that was so far introduced in it, I guess it's not always a bad thing to explore things on my own but It gave me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @DRT, `yield` is not `print`; it represents a generator function. It is a lazy way to retrieve the results of a `for` loop within a function. You can can iterate `summary(xs)` to `print` your values. I updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue is that you don't have enough indices in your inner tuple to unpack into three variables. The simplest way to go around it is to manually unpack **after** checking that you have enough variables, i.e.:

```
def summary(xs):
    for values in xs:
        if values and len(values) == 3:
            x, y, z = values  # or don't unpack, refer to them by index, i.e. v[0], v[1]...
            print(x*x + y*y + z*z)
        else:
            print(0)
```

Or use a `try..except` block:

```
def summary(xs):
    for values in xs:
        try:
            x, y, z = values  # or don't unpack, refer to them by index, i.e. v[0], v[1]...
            print(x*x + y*y + z*z)
        except ValueError:  # check for IndexError if not unpacking
            print(0)
```

Comment: Awesome. I've just edited the code a bit so it works for any kind of tuple (2-tuples, 5 tuples, etc) but this helped nontheless. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "len > 0" condition. This code should work for any list or tuple length :

```
def summary(xs):
    for tup in xs:
        prod = [a*a for a in tup if len(tup)>0]
        print(sum(prod))
```

Note that I defined a "prod" list in order to use "sum" so that it is not calculated the hard way. It replaces your "x* x + y* y + z* z" and works for any tuple length.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It often pays to separate your algorithm into functions that just do one thing. In this case a function to sum the squares of a list of values and a function to print them. It is very helpful to keep your variable names meaningful. In this case your `xs` is a list of lists, so might be better named `xss`

```
import math

def sum_of_squares(xs):
    return sum(map(math.sqr, xs))

def summary(xss):
    for xs in xss:
        print sum_of_squares(xs)

xss = [(2,3,4), (), (1,2,3)]

summary(xss)
```

or

```
map(print, sum(map(math.sqr, (x for x in xs))))
```